# How to get curent cpu mhz on a raspberry pi with python?

Tags: pi-3, python, cpu

I need a sample program that will put the current CPU MHz in a variable with python. I prefer a short compact program. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But do you want to check the CPU speed, or do you want to change the speed on the fly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is four lines, but here it is anyways.
Probably isn't the best way, though.
(oh, and in your script remember to use the shebang for python3)

```
from os import popen
str=popen("vcgencmd measure_clock arm").read()
str = str[str.find("=")+1:-7]
print(str)
```